# How to list records with date from the last 10 days?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT Table.date FROM Table WHERE date > current_date - 10;
```

Does this work on PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 298, accepted):

Yes this does work in PostgreSQL (assuming the column "*date*" is of datatype `date`)
Why don't you just try it?

The standard ANSI SQL format would be:

```
SELECT Table.date 
FROM Table 
WHERE date > current_date - interval '10' day;
```

I prefer that format as it makes things easier to read (but it is the same as `current_date - 10`).

Comment: The query should be: SELECT Table.date 
FROM Table 
WHERE date > current_date - interval '10 day';

Comment: @user2694306: `interval '10 day'` is the Postgres syntax. `interval '10' day` is the syntax based on the SQL standard and also supported by Postgres

Comment: interval should be **9**. **10** actually gives you 11 days back from today.

Comment: @DavidHe: this does the same thing as the original answer. Which uses `10`, not `9`

Comment: Just a note: On Redshift, @user2694306's formulation works: interval '10 day'.  interval '10' day doesn't work on Redshift.

Comment: I can confirm that  '10' day won't work on Redshift, you need to use either '10 day' or '10 days'

Comment: @GinoPane: well the question is about Postgres, not about Redshift.

Comment: Great answer and also work with datetime type apparently. Tested on postgres 10.3 Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: interval '10 day' is NOT a ANSI SQL standard

Answer (score 56):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html shows operators you can use for working with dates and times (and intervals).

So you want

```
SELECT "date"
FROM "Table"
WHERE "date" > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '10 days');
```

The operators/functions above are documented in detail:

- [CURRENT_DATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE)
- [INTERVAL '10 days'](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#OPERATORS-DATETIME-TABLE)

Answer (score 14):

My understanding from my testing (and the [PostgreSQL dox](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#operators-datetime-table)) is that the quotes need to be done differently from the other answers, and should also include "day" like this:

```
SELECT Table.date
  FROM Table 
  WHERE date > current_date - interval '10 day';
```

Demonstrated here (you should be able to run this on any Postgres db):

```
SELECT DISTINCT current_date, 
                current_date - interval '10' day, 
                current_date - interval '10 days' 
  FROM pg_language;
```

Result:

```
2013-03-01  2013-03-01 00:00:00 2013-02-19 00:00:00
```

Comment: Actually, I missed noticing that bradley's answer got it right. Anyway, I'll leave mine here as proof that it's the correct way. The accepted answer is wrong (at least for the version of Postgre I'm running)

Answer (score 10):

The suggested answers already seem to solve the questions. But as an addition I am suggesting to use the NOW() function of PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT Table.date 
FROM Table 
WHERE date > now() - interval '10' day;
```

Additionally you can even specifiy the time zone which can be really handy.

```
NOW () AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris'
```

Answer (score 9):

Starting with Postgres 9.4 you can use the AGE function:

`SELECT Table.date FROM Table WHERE AGE(Table.date) <= INTERVAL '10 day';`

Answer (score 3):

Just generalising the query if you want to work with any given date instead of current date:

```
SELECT Table.date
  FROM Table 
  WHERE Table.date > '2020-01-01'::date - interval '10 day'
```

Comment: this! thx u, this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I would check datatypes.

current_date has "date" datatype, 10 is a number, and Table.date - you need to look at your table.

Answer (score 0):

you can use between too:

```
SELECT Table.date
  FROM Table 
  WHERE date between current_date and current_date - interval '10 day';
```

Comment: The `between` has to be with the lowest value first, so this would be correctly done as

```SELECT Table.date
  FROM Table 
  WHERE date between current_date - interval '10 day' and current_date;
```