# date codeniter 10days from today

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

i need to build a query that will show me all row 10 days from today(AND)also if status is 0

my date in the table is in format   yyyy-mm-dd

```
$this->db->where('status','0')

    ->where('month',date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-40 days')))

  ->get('installments')->result();
```

till now iv only come up with this

p.s Regular Queries will also Do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465484/how-to-list-records-with-date-from-the-last-10-days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 $this->db->where('status','0')
->where("month >=","CURDATE()", false)
        ->where("month <=","current_date + interval '10' day", false)
        ->get('installments')->result();
```

Comment: its not fetching 10 days from today

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: its fetching all the data

Comment: the only thing that is getting filtered is the status  so of 5 rows im getting 3  when it should be 1 with the other date where clause

Comment: do you want date condition on status 1?

Comment: basically i have 5 rows   of which 2 rows are 1st august with status 1  -- 1 row is 9th august status 0  -- and 2 rows are in september with status 0  now i want to only capture values 10 days from today with status 0

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db
    ->where('status','0')
    ->where("month <= '".date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-40 days'))."' AND month >= CURDATE()")
    ->get('installments')
    ->result()
;
```

Comment: It would be nice to add also an explanation about what your code does in relation to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this ..

```
 $this->db->where('status','0')

        ->where('month >= ', DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY))

      ->get('installments')->result();
```

or better syntax

```
$this->db->where(array('status'=>'0','month >= ' => DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY))));
$query=$this->db->get('installments')->result();
```