# Get truncked data from a table - postgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to get truncked data over the last month. My time is in unix timestamps and I need to get data from last 30 days for each specific day.
The data is in the following form:

```
{
"id":"648637",
"exchange_name":"BYBIT",
"exchange_icon_url":"https://cryptowisdom.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Bybit-colored-logo.png",
"trade_time":"1675262081986",
"price_in_quote_asset":23057.5,
"price_in_usd":1,
"trade_value":60180.075,
"base_asset_icon":"https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png?1547033579",
"qty":2.61,
"quoteqty":60180.075,
"is_buyer_maker":true,
"pair":"BTCUSDT",
"base_asset_trade":"BTC",
"quote_asset_trade":"USDT"
}
```

I need to truncate data based on `trade_time`
How do I write the query?

[image]

Comment: Could you give an example of what you expect the output to look like? I'm a little confused about how "data from last 30 days for each specific day" would look.

Comment: Yes, I would like to get the count of trades `COUNT(*)` for each day. Like how many trades happened in that particular day.

Comment: It's unclear to me if you want to convert your data to JSON, or if you want to query those JSON values with a specific condition.

Comment: I just want a query that returns this result, the rest is being handled by a REST Api that runs the query

Comment: `age(trade_time) <= interval '30 days'` should be a good way to filter out results 30 days older or less. Check out docs for [Date/Time Functions}(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secret sauce is the `date_trunc` function, which takes a `timestamp with time zone` and truncates it to a specific precision (hour, day, week, etc). You can then group based on this value.

In your case we need to convert these <s>unix timestamps</s> javascript style timestamps to `timestamp with time zone` first, which we can do with `to_timestamp`, but it's still a fairly simple query.

```sql
SELECT
    date_trunc('day', to_timestamp(trade_time / 1000.0)),
    COUNT(1)
FROM pings_raw
GROUP BY date_trunc('day', to_timestamp(trade_time / 1000.0))
```

Another approach would be to leave everything as numbers, which might be marginally faster, though I find it less readable

```sql
SELECT
    (trade_time/(1000*60*60*24))::int * (1000*60*60*24),
    COUNT(1)
FROM pings_raw
GROUP BY (trade_time/(1000*60*60*24))::int
```

Comment: The dates are weird and the count is also either 1 or 2.

Comment: @HusnainMehmood In what way are they weird?

Comment: There should be 30 rows with amount of trades on every day. Instead I am getting around 1000s of responses and the dates are weird. (adding the picture in my question for reference)

Comment: @HusnainMehmood I'm going to take a guess that the values in your database are not unix timestamps. Unix timestamps are 10 digits (for anything from 2002 to 2286).

Comment: They are but they are 13 digits so I am guessing they are in nanoseconds?

Comment: We are getting all the days in the db. We need the last 30 days. Can we limit that?

Comment: @HusnainMehmood I have updated the answer to deal with nanoseconds. As for limiting to only the last 30 days, that would just be a `WHERE` clause ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465484/how-to-list-records-with-date-from-the-last-10-days))